# Touchstart and touchend not working on iOS using jquery mobile and cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, cordova

In a previous project I had no issue with the below code for using the touchstart and touchend events to modify the css of a button:

```
<script>

$('input[type="button"]').on('touchstart', function(e){
$(this).css('background-color','#49D623');
                                       });

$('input[type="button"]').on('touchend', function(e){
              $(this).css('background-color','');
              });

</script>
```

This was in an iOS cordova project using version 2.9.0

Since I have upgraded to the cordova 3.2 and am using jquery mobile 1.4.0 with jquery 1.10.2 and the same above code no longer works.

I have tried `.on(touchstart` and `.bind(touchstart` and `.live(touchstart` worked with jquery 1.8 but is deprecated in 1.9. I have also tried using the id of the button, but that does not work either.

I know that the touchstart is being recognized as I have tested it to fire off other functions and it works like a charm, just not for this.

This is how the button appears in my html:

```
<input type="button" id="submit" data-role="none">
```

The css of the relevant button:

```
input[type="button"] {

-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0px;
width: 92%;
margin-top: 3%;
margin-left: 5%;
background-color: rgba(23,24,54,1.00);
padding: 10px;
border-width: 1px;
border-color:rgba(88,88,88,1.00);
font-size: 1em;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'HelveticaNeue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
background-image: url(../img/padlock2.png);
background-size: 20px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;

    }
```

The below are referenced in the head of my html file:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquerymobile1.4rc1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/globalstyles.css">
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: it working fine. Make sure you bind events to `pagecreate` as in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/tPNNv/). Also, use jQM 1.4 stylesheet not 1.4RC1.

Comment: That's what I was missing, I didn't realise you needed to bind to pagecreate for the touchstart to work. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will fix your problem, but the .live() method is deprecated. try using the .on() method in place of it. Also try replacing touchstart and touchend with mousedown and mouseup, and see if that does the trick. Here is a [plunker where i got something similar to work](http://plnkr.co/edit/i3RX9diuXTIoK9x2qqGR?p=preview)

Comment: I don't think mouseup mousedown is right since this is a touch device oriented design and no cursor is ever involved. Oddly I cannot seem to get the background color property to work at all, I think the problem lies there, if the background color property isnt being applied the script to alter the background color on touchstart touchend obviously will not work either.